# scope.$watch doesn't work in directive

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have custom angularjs directive and `click` handler in it like:

```
element.bind('click', function () {
  scope.checked = !scope.checked;
});
```

And i want to catch when `scope.checked` is changing, i'm trying to so with:

```
scope.$watch(scope.checked, function(val){
  console.log(val);
});
```

But i don't see anything.

Thank you.

Comment: A typo? It should be scope.$watch('checked', function(val) [...]

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right, thank you, can you post your answer and i will accept it, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a typo; it's:

```
scope.$watch('checked', function(val){
  console.log(val);
});
```

Reference: [http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.16/docs/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)